# Select Layer by Location using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

i want to create a python scipt query using arpy in arcgis
i have one polyline shapefile and one polygon shapefile i want to choose(select) the polygons where contained within in the polylines shapefiles or there intersections and finaly i want that select polygons to export to new shapefile layer.
i use arcmap 10.1

my code is

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *


arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
try:
arcpy.env.workspace = root
root = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
polygon = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
line =  arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
except:
arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())
try:
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(polygon, "INTERSECT", line, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion("polygon", newpolygon)
newpolygon = root + "\\newpolygon"
except:
arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

i use that code but i dont take Correct Results my root workspace is empty

any idea ?

Comment: You attempt to use the variable "newpolygon" before it is assigned a value.

Comment: Similarly, as Leroy points out below, you attempt to use "root" before it is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

This script can be further edited but commonly this script should work

```
import arcpy

# Script arguments
Search_Distance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

Selection_type = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if Selection_type == '#' or not Selection_type:
    Selection_type = "NEW_SELECTION" # provide a default value if unspecified

Source_Layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

Relationship = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
if Relationship == '#' or not Relationship:
    Relationship = "INTERSECT" # provide a default value if unspecified

Target_Layers__Select_From_ = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

Output_Layer_Name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)

Output_Layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)

Workspace_or_Feature_Dataset = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)

# Local variables:

# Process: Select Layer By Location
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Target_Layers__Select_From_, Relationship, Source_Layer, Search_Distance, Selection_type)

# Process: Make Feature Layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Output_Layer_Name, Output_Layer, "", Workspace_or_Feature_Dataset, "")
```

Thanks.

Comment: thank you but not help me that :(

Answer (score 1):

```
import arcpy

polygon = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # input polygon feature class
line =  arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # input line feature class
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) # output polygon feature class

# make polygon feature layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(polygon, 'polygon_lyr') 
# select polygons
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('polygon_lyr', "INTERSECT", line, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
# save selection to output
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('polygon_lyr', output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place 'root = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)' before 'arcpy.env.workspace = root' and that should sort it. Watch your script indentation too :)